# Laravel 7 Trait not found

Tags: php, laravel, traits

Hello I have problem when pushing my laravel project to the server with the Trait.

- My project works perfectly on local but on server, when i try `composer install` I got the error `Trait 'App\Traits\LoggedCommand' not found`

This is my trait named LoggedCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Services\TaskScheduleLoggerService;

trait LoggedCommand {
   // code
}
```

And this is where i want to use the Trait i have registered

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Services\ProductUpdaterService;
use App\Traits\LoggedCommand;

class updateProductsData extends Command
{

}
```

Any one knows about this problems? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: it return the trait not found again! :/ anything like php artisan commands dont work

Comment: Double check your file/path capitalisations - I've found that to be a common issue when something works locally but not on the server.

Comment: is your 'traits' directory named `Traits`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```php
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

Comment: this is not valid

Comment: It returns Trait 'App\Traits\LoggedCommand' not found again. I can not run any command like php artisan even

Comment: your site is on any VPS or cpanel?

Comment: VPS with centos 7

Comment: have you use it like this?

<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Services\ProductUpdaterService;
use App\Traits\LoggedCommand;

class updateProductsData extends Command
{
     use  LoggedCommand; 
}

Comment: Yes exactly! That's how I use the command

Answer (score 0):

composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear

Comment: It returns the same problems. I can not use any command lines like php artisan ... or composer ... it returns the same problems!